# How is volatility surface re-calibrated with new inputs?

Tags: volatility, commodities

I'm a newby on this topic so please bear with me. My question is:

I've a strike by strike / listed products volatility surface, and I was asking how can I recalibrate my surface during the day considering the new prices.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by having a vol surface? That surface must be computed somehow if it's from listed, price quoted options. Whenever you recompute it, you have a new surface.